# run php script every 5 seconds

Tags: php, shell, cron

I know that for running php script every time (seconds or minute) we can use Cron (job or tab) but cron has a 60 sec granularity so we are forced to have an infinite loop for running php script . For example we can write the code below to call it at the top of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]; do   
   #put php script here
done
```

but it's illogical because we must change php execution time in php.ini so we have a lot of problems (Security , overflow , ... ) in server . well, what should we do exactly ?
My question is how to run php script every 5 seconds that hasn't got problems in php execution time .

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why do you have to change anything in `php.ini`? The time limit there is just for a single script, not the combined time of all the scripts run by this shell script.

Comment: BTW, it should be `while :; do`. You don't need to test anything for an infinite loop.

Comment: // please try this // $url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

header("Refresh: 5; URL=$url1");

Comment: @Arun doesn't that require to have a browser window open all the time?

Answer (score 4):

Use Cron job script. Get a 30 seconds interval , you could delay by 5 seconds:

```
-*/5-22 * * * sleep 5;your_script.php
```

The above script will run 5am to 10 pm

Another Alternative is,

```
You need to write a shell script like this that sleeps on the specified interval and schedule that to run every minute in cron:

#!/bin/sh
# Script: delay_cmd
sleep $1
shift
$*
```

Then schedule that to run in cron with your parameters: delay_cmd 5 mycommand parameters

Answer (score 2):

```
 #!/bin/sh

 #

 SNOOZE=5

 COMMAND="/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php"

 LOG=/var/log/httpd/script_log.log

 echo `date` "starting..." >> ${LOG} 2>&1

 while true

 do

  ${COMMAND} >> ${LOG} 2>&1

  echo `date` "sleeping..." >> ${LOG} 2>&1

  sleep ${SNOOZE}

 done
```

---

The above script will run at a second interval.
It will not run the `PHP` script when it is still processing, also reports the interaction/errors inside a log file.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the sleep function to delay every 5 seconds

int sleep ( int $seconds ) - Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere to use sleep in your PHP

```
    while( true ) {

        // function();

        sleep( 5 );

    }
```

You can stop it after 1 Minute or something like that and restart it with a cronjob. With this solution you are able to execute your script every second after your last executing and it works not asynchronously.

You save ressources with that solution, because php have not to restart all the time...