# Run a php script every 5 seconds by using a shell script

Tags: php, json, shell, cron

I would like to run a php script every 5 seconds.

That's what I've done :

(essay.sh file)

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    php a_file.php
    sleep 5
done
```

(the php file in a nutshell)

```
<?php
// sql call

// sql into $json

$file = 'json.txt';

file_put_contents($file, $json);
?>
```

There is no error when I do: ./essay.sh, but the json.txt is not refreshed (nothing happen, and I've set the rights to 0755 for the both files).

When I use the direct url of a_file.php in my browser the script is working, and a new json.txt is generated.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't think running script every 5 mins can be done except using cronjob.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to do it every 5 seconds and cron is limited to 1 minute at least

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898231/run-php-script-every-5-seconds

Comment: You could create a [daemon in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process) that basically runs forever once start (either through cron or at system start). Allow the daemon to do some work and then sleep for 5 seconds. You could even fork processes depending on your situation.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? i.e., why does it need to run every 5 seconds?  There may be a more efficient solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your script in my pc and found out it works fine. This is the file privilege i set:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I've no error from shell but the txt file is not overwrited by the supposed loaded php file by the shell script. And rights are: rwxrwxrwx for essay.sh and rwxrwxr-x for the php script and rwxrwxr-x for the txt file.

Comment: is the txt file created? check the file update time instead of content?

Comment: Yes it is and the time is not ./essay.sh (yet). Did you tried to create a txt file like me on the php script?

Comment: @Alex1 change script privelege to777?

Comment: The 3 files to 777 (same directory) and nothing happen

Comment: Ok it works with a different php script. Sorry but the php script itself presents no error... and can be loaded. I'll investigate this.

Comment: I've forgot to set the rights for the called files on the require_once function of php. Thank you! It works now!

Comment: @Alex1 ok. no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because your are setting 0755 you need to run your script as the same user as the owner of the json file.

Try to set the permissions to 775 or run the script as the owner of that json file.

Comment: Hi, still nothing happen.

Comment: nevertheless, you should really consider using a cronjob instead of sleep in php :-)

Comment: Thank you for the importance of the permissions