# Cron to run a PHP Script every 5 seconds between time slots

Tags: php, api, cron, cron-task, py-telegram-bot-api

How to run the PHP Script automatically **every 5 seconds** between the time slots **13:00:00 to 14:00:00** and **16:00:00 to 17:00:00** everyday?

PHP Script :

```
<?php
$datetime = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A"); 
$apiToken = "1825671537:AAEYexjklpoiyUdEeG8Ml";
$telegram_chatid = '-10012345607';
$message = urlencode($datetime);
                
$telegram_call = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?chat_id=$telegram_chatid&parse_mode=markdown&text=$message");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: AFAIK cron can only run things once per minute, maximum. Looks like you're just spamming a telegram thingy with pointless timing data though, what is the purpose?

Comment: @ADyson this is just an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run php script every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898231/run-php-script-every-5-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to run the process 12 times with a 5-second `sleep` between calls. Use cron to run this every minute.

```
* 13  * * *  for i in {1..12}; do (php telegram.php &); sleep 5; done;
* 16  * * *  for i in {1..12}; do (php telegram.php &); sleep 5; done;
```

The program is detached using `&`, so the sleep happens directly and not after the script is finished, ensuring it's run every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't do it with the cron job but you can use the cron job as an initiator.

This could be a way to solve this issue. you can run a cron job everyday at 13:00 o'clock.

Your script on the other hand should have a loop which sleeps 5 second and goes again through the loop. Once you reach 17:00 o'clock it will stop the loop and exit.

And there should be another check in the loop, which checks whether you are between the given time e.g. 13:00-14:00 or 16:00-17:00, if so it will run your script and sleep 5 seconds, if not it will just run the the loop

Another way would be to run a cron job every hour.
And in your script you have to check it the hour is the one you want to start doing something. if so, you just do it like the above loop.